# Is there any way to reset the SMART data of hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

I want to reset the "worst" case of the SMART's read error rate (currently at 100/max). The reason is simple: I don't want to be hassled by (1) the "press F1 to continue" for the error message at startup and (2) the random messages of Windows 7 to backup because of a hard disk problem.

The disk is working fine for me for most purposes. I have no problem with the data on the hard disk, and I plan to continue using the hard disk until it dies, anyway.

Of course, I have considered getting a new hard disk, but for the time being, I would be grateful if I wouldn't be pestered by the messages.

The hard disk is an old Hitachi Travelstar 80gb IDE for the laptop, in case it's needed.

(Side question: Will the disk still be usable if I reformat?)

Comment: The drive is failing, why use a failing drive?

Comment: Since I currently have no other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want SMART messages on boot, your BIOS may support simply turning it off.

Otherwise, you should address this question to Hitachi Support, as I believe that they have a utility that can clear SMART. Do not use any utility not from Hitachi, as there is a great risk of bricking the disk.

Comment: I wasn't aware that such utility exists. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

> SMART is an internal drive sector-reallocation table - when the drive detected a screwed up sector, it uses SMART to store the data on some other sector.
>
> You never want to re-set the SMART data - that is asking to deliberately use all the known bad sectors on the drive again.

See post by [cnd4](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/reset-s-m-r-t-data-t1943214p2.html)

Comment: I see. I guess I should just live with it. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, even if it is for testing purposes, no need to dodge the question, people can skip it, and that's ok

Comment: Even if it makes the drive unusable?